# How to perform a negative query in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How to perform a query (.find) in MongoDB indicating that I do NOT want a word to appear in one of the document fields.

Thanks

I dont know the excatly command

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `$not` and `$regex` operators:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "field": {
    "$not": {
      "$regex": "some"
    }
  }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/S1tpqfrUuw8)